# Is it better to run checkdisk on a secondary driver?

Tags: check-disk

I want to run checkdisk on my main driver. However, is it better to run it on a computer where I install it as a secondary drive?

My point is that if the program is running on the same hardrive on which it is fixing errors, is it possible it cannot fixes some zone it is using to run the tests?

Comment: If the zone the tests run from was damaged, wouldn't checkdisk not run?

Comment: *"...on my main driver."* -- Driver??? Driver is usually software.  *" if the program is running on the same hardrive"* -- Programs don't literally *"run"* on a storage device.  If the program can be read (i.e. loaded) without errors, the program will execute from memory, and can access/test any device you direct it to.

Comment: -1  if you don't even get the name of the program correct it's a hazard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify some terminology.

The proper command is called `chkdsk` and is usually referred to as such.

Your disk drives are called `drives` for short.

Now, in regards to running `chkdsk` on your disk drives, it doesn't matter if it is primary or secondary. Chkdsk will not run in "fix" mode on a mounted disk drive. Instead you will be prompted to dismount the drive, or in the case of a primary drive, to schedule chkdsk during the next reboot.

This eliminates the possibility of the drive being in use during the scan.

Comment: thanks! I actually did it on boot... but then I though that even on booting it uses stuff installed on the primary drive? I though chkdsk was installed on this drive?

Comment: @Cher main thing is you can't go wrong on the question of which drive to run chkdsk from. How it works is another matter/question..